# How can I keep both MySQL databases consistent in master-master replication after recovering from failed event?

Tags: mysql, master-master-replication

I was given a task to fix the sync issue between 2 database servers where I had two MySQL database servers set up with master-master replication. They were working normally but one of the servers was stuck due to errors in executing the events received from the master. I ran the following command on the slave and found the error in the output.

```
show slave status
```

I got `Slave_IO_Running = Yes`, `Slave_SQL_Running = No`and `Last_Error` was showing Duplicate error message.

While searching for the fix I got a solution where we can skip the failed event one by one until the slave can successfully execute the events received from the server.

The solution I applied:

```
STOP SLAVE;    
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;
START SLAVE;
```

My question is that when I am skipping the events in this way I believe it might lead to the inconsistency in the databases so what steps I should take so both databases would be having consistent state without the need of taking the full backup of one database and then restoring it at the other database.

As I am new to this concept, it would be great if suggestions can be grasped easily. :)

Comment: When you run into duplicate key errors, you already have inconsistent data and you can't fully trust your data anymore. The only way to fix this, is to re-setup the replication with a fresh backup. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Using `SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER` only "kicks the can down the road".